# A doubt about the topic of motional emf from Griffiths

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Consider a closed rectangular loop of wire, which is moved to the right with a velocity ${\vec v}$ w.r.t a magnet that provides a static, uniform magnetic field $\vec B=-B\hat{z}$ over a region as shown in figure 7.10 of *Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths* (3rd edition).

He says that in this case, the magnetic force $\vec F_B$ does not do any work on the charges but the agent which is pulling the loop towards the right does work on the charge carriers. Since the charge carriers have a drift velocity $\vec u$ along the wire, its resultant velocity is $${\vec w}={\vec u}+{\vec v}=u\hat{y}+v\hat{x}$$ w.r.t the magnet. Clearly, the net power supplied to the charges by the magnetic field $$P=\vec w\cdot \vec{F}_B={\vec w}\cdot q(\vec w\times\vec B)=0$$ as Griffiths explains.

But note that we can break the magnetic force $\vec F_B$ into two perpendicular components: one parallel to ${\vec u}=u\hat{y}$ and another parallel to ${\vec v}=v\hat{x}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\vec F}_B= q({\vec w}\times{\vec B})= q[\{({\vec w}\times{\vec B})\cdot\hat{y}\}\hat{y} +\{({\vec w}\times{\vec B})\cdot\hat{x}\}\hat{x}]\\
= q[\{({\vec v}\times{\vec B})\cdot\hat{y}\}\hat{y} +\{({\vec u}\times{\vec B})\cdot\hat{x}\}\hat{x}]\\ 
=-qBu\hat{x}+qBv\hat{y}
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore, the rate of work done on the charges have two parts:
$$P=\vec w\cdot \vec{F}_B=(u\hat{y}+v\hat{x})\cdot(-qBu\hat{x}+qBv\hat{y})=-qvBu+qvBu$$ where we see that one term in the expression for $P$ is positive and the other term is negative but of equal magnitude so that the net power $P=0$.

Thus, one component of $\vec F_B$ does a positive work on the charges (power is dumped into the charges?) and the other component does an equal but negative work on the charges (power is extracted from the charges?). How should we interpret the negative work done on the charges? It's like the power is delivered to the charges by the vertical component of $\vec F_B$ and extracted from the charges by the horizontal component of $\vec F_B$.

Griffiths says that the Magnetic force does not do any work and the work is really done by the external agent pulling the loop. But is that completely satisfactory? The magnetic force may not work as a whole but it has a component $qvB\hat{y}$ acting along the vertical segments wire and that indeed does positive work on the charges.

Answer (score 0):

> How should we interpret the negative work done on the charges? Does it mean that the charges deliver energy to the magnet? Where does that energy go?

All that matters is the net work. The "work done by the components" is just a mathematical trick. At the end of the day the physical results shouldn't depend on our choice of how we represent the vectors and their components. There is no energy transfer; that's all there is to it.

Comment: The charge carriers experience a magnetic force $qvB\hat{y}$ in the vertical direction. Should not that accelerate the charges down the wire?

Comment: @Solidification If that was the only force, yes, but there is a resistor too. But that's a red herring. You have shown the total work done by the magnetic force is $0$. It doesn't matter if there is acceleration or not.

Comment: Griffiths himself says that the vertical component of magnetic force drives the current in the loop. Then, he says that the external agent supplies the energy. This is confusing. Isn't it odd that the vertical component of the magnetic force drives the current while the force pulling the wire supplies the energy?

Comment: @Solidification It's not odd. Check out figure 5.12 and its description on page 211 for a mechanical analogy that is easier to grasp.